# use drivers from old kernel in new kernel

Tags: drivers, linux-kernel, raspbian

I am using newest Raspbian but I found out stk1160 drivers are not working properly. But in older raspbian it works ok. So I would like to move drivers from older Raspbian to newer Raspbian. How can I do it?

Comment: You can't, or at least not in a reliable way.  You can go back to using an older kernel, though.

Answer (score 1):

As goldilocks pointed [out in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148338/use-drivers-from-old-kernel-in-new-kernel#comment240626_148338), there's no "reliable way" to do this. There are many ways the driver could be broken that even if you manage to import it, it may present the same or other problems. The best way to go is to report a bug, explaining the problem and what kernel you didn't found the problem, so they can review the relevant code and revert the changes or adapt the code.

Comment: And what happens if I copy file from /lib/modules/3.10.25+/kernel/drivers/media/usb/stk1160/stk1160.ko to the same location of new raspbian? Could it work? In the new file is just few lines changed so I think it is not working properly because of this.

Comment: it is not just as easy as I thought. Simple copy does not work.